# uitabbarcontroller not working properly in xamarin iOS mono touch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin

i have created uitabbarcontroller which is not properly working,my issue is if i click second tab bar the corresponding view is not visible only the first view is visible for all actions.i couldn't navigate  and see the next views.

my code is :

```
  if (this.tabBarController == null) 


      {     

    this.tabBarController = new UITabBarController ();      

        }  

      var viewController1=new Filterview();   

      var viewController2=new SearchView();

      tabBarController = new UITabBarController ();     

  tabBarController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController []

         {                      

           viewController1, 

        viewController2,    

          } ;  

     viewController2.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem (UITabBarSystemItem.Search, 1); 


     viewController1.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem ("Filter", UIImage.FromFile ("Images/1382614124_filter.png"), 0);

      this.NavigationController.PushViewController (this.tabBarController, true);
```

this code is not working pl anybody suggest me how to create uitabbar in iOS xamarin mono touch applications.

Answer (score 3):

`UITabBarController` is a root controller. This means it is supposed as the topmost controller in your hierarchy. You are pushing this controller on a `UINavigationController`.
This is most probably causing the issues you see.
Try to set your tab bar controller in your app delegate:

```
window.RootViewController = someTabBarController;
```

Let me quote from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the
>   root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar
>   interface should never be installed as a child of another view
>   controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot will implement and let you know